# Reverse cross product

Tags: vectors

Good afternoon,

I am currently having issues solving a problem:

> Let $A$ and $B$ have position vectors $a = 2i – j + 3k$ and $b = 5i – 2j + k$ 
>   respectively. The force $F = 3i – 5j – k$ passes through the point $A$.
>   Show that the vector moment of force, $\vec F$ about the point $B$ is equal to
>   $3(3i + j + 4k)$.

I was thinking I could simply solve a system of linear equations to find the moment of the force, and once I have obtained it, do the cross product of $\vec r (B)$ for the newly found $\vec M$. Apparently however there are better ways to solve the problem but I can't really find any.

Answer (score 1):

The moment of a force is $\vec M=\vec r\times\vec F$ where $\vec r$ is the position vector from the point about which you are taking the moment to the point of application of the force.

So in this case, the moment about point $B$ of force applied at point $A$ is $\vec M=(\vec a-\vec b)\times\vec F$, because $\vec a-\vec b$ is the position vector from $A$ to $B$.

$$(\vec a-\vec b)\times\vec F=\begin{vmatrix}
\vec i & \vec j & \vec k \\
(2-5) & (-1+2) & (3-1) \\
3 & -5 & -1 \\
\end{vmatrix}=9\vec i +3\vec j +12\vec k$$

Answer (score 0):

The moment of the vector $\vec{F}$ passing through a point $\vec{a}$ measured at a point $\vec{b}$ is simply (by definition)

$$ \vec{M} = (\vec{a}-\vec{b}) \times \vec{F} $$

The relative position of the force from the point of measurements being

$$ \vec{a}-\vec{b} = \pmatrix{ -3 \\ 1 \\2} $$

and the moment

$$ \vec{M} = \pmatrix{ -3 \\ 1 \\2} \times \pmatrix{3 \\ -5 \\ -1} = \pmatrix{9 \\ 3 \\12} $$